# Foreign key or copy of attributes in log entities

Tags: foreign-key, erd

I am trying to design an ER for a system with the following specifications:

> 1. Each user has an account
> 2. The user can link his/her bank accounts to his/her account in our system
> 3. The user can deposit or withdraw money to his/her account in our system and we must keep the history of these transactions

I have designed it like this so far(discarding unrelated details):

[image]

**My question is:** Is it good design to keep the `Account ID` as an attribute instead of a keeping a foreign key to the `Account` entity? Because deleting an account shouldn't affect its transaction logs. i.e. [this design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtfQF.png) instead of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwmgL.png).

Also how about the case in general? (doing the same for any logging entity whose existence doesn't depend on the source entity). Thanks.

Comment: "Is it good design?"  No, it's far worse to have stray transactions.  Set an `IsActive` flag on `Account` - under no circumstances should you handle money but destroy information related to an account.

Comment: @bbaird thanks a lot for your answer. I understand thats a far better approach. But what about this special case when only "one" "unchangable" attribute is needed?

Comment: That is not an ordinary attribute, it is part of a key.  You may want to go back to the drawing board or use a diagramming method that makes PK-FKs more explicit.